# Div Wrapper childern setArribute offset

Tags: javascript, html, offset, children

I am adding a wrapper to a division and trying to set offset right as follow:

```
                var wrapper_div = document.getElementById('container1');
                var kinetic_div = wrapper_div.children[0];
                canvaso = kinetic_div.children[0];
                canvaso.setAttribute('id', "panel1");
                canvaso.setAttribute('offset', '100px');
```

Unfortunately it does not work!  Would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: There is no native `offset` attribute or style, so what are you expecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
canvaso.style.offset = '100px;'
```

or

```
canvaso.setAttribute('style','offset:100px;');
```

I presume that you are trying to change the style.